# how do I stop playing audio using the same button

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

My code plays an audio when the button is clicked but It does not pause when I click it again.

I want to use the same button to play and pause the audio using js.

```js
const rollSound = new Audio

("sounds/short-guided-meditation.ogg");
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", e => rollSound.play());
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: I still need an answer. Please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is described at [MDN HTMLMediaElement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), you can check whether is Media element `.paused` and decide if you would like to `play()` or `stop()`. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", e => rollSound.paused ? rollSound.play() : rollSound.pause());
```

Snippet example:

```js
const rollSound = document.getElementById('rollSound');
const btn = document.getElementById('play');

btn.addEventListener("click", e => rollSound.paused ? rollSound.play() : rollSound.pause());
```

```html
<audio id=rollSound loop>
  <source src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/digital_watch_alarm_long.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<button id=play>play/stop</button>
```

Comment: Hi dear, thankyou so much for taking your time to help a stranger. I replaced the line with the code you provided but unfortunately, it still only played when it was clicked. Is there anything you can suggest?        `<button class="playsound" id="play" onclick=" rollSound.play()" >Play/Pause </button>`    Here is the html code for it if needed. thanks again.

Comment: @heleni I just added a full working snippet for you to try it out on. I hope it helps.

Comment: thankyou so much for your help jax. your code works perfectly, but I don't know why it wont work in my website.   the audio that you used, was it in a folder or by itself?